# How to calculate timestamp from UNIX UTC for a date that is not my timezone

Tags: javascript, date, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am developing a weather app and I'm trying to retrieve the sunrise and sunset times. These values come in UNIX UTC format and I'm able to transform them into date and time, but the time always seem to be parsed into ***my*** local time.

For instance, if I'm retreiving the sunrise time for Madrid (which is my timezone) I will get 7:30. But when I retreive the sunrise for New York, I get 12:30, which is obviously not correct. Is there an easy fix for this in JavaScript?

Comment: See [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and look at the functions that include "UTC" in their name.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the sunrise or sunset time in the correct timezone using [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), this accepts an [`IANA timezone`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

I've created a simple function that will take sunrise and sunset times in Unix format (seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00) and display in the relevant local time.

```js
const sunriseUnix = 1660903800;
const sunsetUnix = 1660952880;

function showSunTimes(sunriseUnix, sunsetUnix, timeZone) {
    console.log(`Sunrise (${timeZone}):`, new Date(sunriseUnix * 1000).toLocaleString('default', { timeZone }));
    console.log(`Sunset (${timeZone}):`, new Date(sunsetUnix * 1000).toLocaleString('default', { timeZone }));
}

showSunTimes(sunriseUnix, sunsetUnix, 'America/New_York');
showSunTimes(sunriseUnix, sunsetUnix, 'UTC');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```